# New Security Risk? - Bluetooth device paired with Windows even though onboard Bluetooth is disabled in BIOS

Tags: audio, security, android, bluetooth, windows-11

I had a really weird experience with my desktop computer. Even though Bluetooth was disabled in BIOS, I started hearing audio playback from Momentum 4 wireless Bluetooth headphones after connecting them to Samsung S23. I could also control YouTube playback (start & stop) with the headphones.

##### Background info (Desktop)

- Windows 11 Pro: Latest updates installed
- Asus Z790 Creator: Onboard Bluetooth disabled in BIOS (Bios version 0816)
- Asus z790 Creator: Onboard WiFi disabled in Bios (I don't other WiFi devices, either)
- Connected devices: Logitech Bolt (Mouse & Keyboard), RME Audio Interface, Kingston SD Reader
- Monitor: LG 40WP95C-W, connected via mini Displayport - USB-C cable from RTX 4070 Ti

##### Background info (S23)

- Latest firmware installed
- Latest updates installed

##### What happened?

1. Paired Momentum 4 headphones with Samsung S23
2. Installed Sennheiser Smart control app on Samsung S23
3. Updated Momentum 4 firmware
4. Went to my desktop and wondered why I cannot hear the sound
5. Realized that audio playback is coming from Momentum 4 headphones

I don't know at which point Windows connected to Momentum 4 headphones

##### Findings

- Asus Z790: Onboard Bluetooth still disabled
- Asus Z790: Onboard WiFi still disabled
- Windows 11: Bluetooth on-off switch  not shown
- Windows 11: Momentum 4 shown under "Bluetooth & Devices > Devices > Audio"
- Windows 11: "System > Sound > Volume Mixer" Momentum 4 shown as Output device and Input device
- Smart Control App (S23): "Momentum 4 > Connection Management" Only Galaxy S23 shown, Desktop not shown.

Thus, Sennhaiser Smart Control App doesn't know that Momentum 4 is connected to Windows 11.

##### Replication

4. Removed Momentum 4 from Windows 11 "Bluetooth & Devices > Devices > Audio"
5. Could not replicate steps 1-3

##### Notes

I should have removed Logitech Bolt receiver while the audio was playing from the headphones just to what happens. However, it was too late when I realized this. I also should have tested what happens if I put other Bluetooth devices in pairing mode.

##### Turning Bluetooth on

6. ASUS Z790: Enabled onboard Bluetooth
7. Restarted
8. Connected Momentum 4 to Desktop

##### Findings

- Windows 11: Momentum 4 shown under "Bluetooth & Devices > Devices > Audio"
- Windows 11: Bluetooth on-off switch is shown
- Windows 11: "System > Sound > Volume Mixer" Momentum 4 shown as Output device and Input device
- Smart Control App (S23): "Momentum 4 > Connection Management" Both Galaxy S23 and Desktop are shown
- Windows 11: Audio playback from Momentum 4 headphones works fine

##### Possible diagnosis

The following devices don't have a Bluetooth connection: RME Audio Interface, Kingston SD Reader, LG 40WP95C-W1

Thus, there are pretty much only two of explanations that I can think of and all of them seem very unlikely.

a) The Bluetooth connection has been formed with Logitech Bolt receiver
b) The onboard Bluetooth device could be on even though it's disabled in BIOS

There are no other Bluetooth receivers connected to my desktop.
Samsung S23 and the desktop should not be connected in any other way, either.

a) Bolt receiver should not work with other Bluetooth peripherals. "Likewise, both Unifying and Bolt are proprietary technologies from Logitech. Therefore, they're not compatible with wireless peripherals from other brands." (makeuseof.com)
b) I've never heard that devices that are disabled in BIOS could work.

##### Security Risk

If peripherals are able to connect to Windows 11 even though Bluetooth is off, this sounds like a security risk.

##### Bios Update

I updated Z790 Bios from version 8016 to 0904. I'll be reinstalling Windows 11 in a few days. I will check if I'm able to replicate this issue.

##### Questions

1. Do you have any idea how Momentum 4 was able to connect to Windows 11? It there something obvious that I'm just missing?
2. f I don't want my desktop to connect to Bluetooth devices automatically which one of these is a safer option?

a) Enable onboard Bluetooth device and disable Bluetooth from Windows.
b) Disable onboard Bluetooth and hope that this kind of situation doesn't happen again.

Comment: Sanity check. AFAIK the headphones can use a mini jack or so. Was it not in use? Were all cables disconnected?

Comment: All cables were disconnected.

Comment: Some Bluetooth API of Windows caches found devices up to 24 hours. I would assume that you see those cached devices even with disabled Bluetooth.

Comment: Momentum 4 headphones had never been connected to this desktop before

Comment: I live next to a street where a lot of people walk by with their Bluetooth headphones. My PC was never paired with any of these devices but they are shown (50-70 devices per day) and they are for example visible in tools like [BLEConsole](https://github.com/sensboston/BLEConsole) and even shut down my PC and move it somewhere else, the next day those devices are still listed. So it seems to be sufficient if the device was advertising it's name.

Comment: @TK_24816 - Have you considered the reason you were able to audio is because of the Sennheiser Smart software and NOT because a BT device was connected to your system despite the fact the BT device was disabled?

Comment: I installed Sennheiser Smart Control App on my phone. I was able to hear Youtube playback from my Desktop. My phone and my desktop are not synced or connected and I don't use same Youtube accounts with them

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best explanation I've got:

"I think that what is happening is that when you disable it in BIOS, the firmware is like "okay, we won't tell windows about this device", so when windows boots and it asks the chipset "hey, what devices do you have?" it gives the whole list and leaves out the BT adapter. But it doesn't *actually* disable anything by, like, cutting power to it. And there is some watchdog in the firmware that basically watches for any incoming connections and when it sees one it doesn't even stop to check if the adapter is enabled or disabled, it just straight up forwards the handshake to the OS. Windows, being the helpful friendly neighborhood OS it is, say's "Oh cool, a handshake? I know what to do with those" and just establishes the connection and, it being a new audio device, starts using it."

https://linustechtips.com/topic/1506628-security-risk-bluetooth-device-paired-with-windows-even-though-onboard-bluetooth-is-disabled-in-bios/#comment-15941768